# Why won't Rails Console Use Database URL Like Rails Server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

All of a sudden, `rails console` will only use my local database, whereas `rails server` continues to use my Heroku database. Why is this happening and how do I get rails console to use my Heroku database like it used to?

Here is how Heroku recommends we do what I'm trying to do: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-to-heroku-postgres-databases-from-outside-of-heroku#credentials

This uses my heroku database:

```
DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL) rails server
```

This uses my local database:

```
DATABASE_URL=$(heroku config:get DATABASE_URL) rails console
```

Comment: start console in production environment rails c -e production

Comment: You can use `heroku run rails c` to access heroku database.

Comment: Please show your database.yml

Comment: I want to be able to run `rails console` with the `DATABASE_URL` environment variable. For some reason it stopped working for `rails console` but still works for `rails server`.